# How to determine if an image is higher/lower in brightness/saturation?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, imageview, python-imaging-library

I use Python, and I have a dataset, in which there are some images and the exercises says something like this:

- If the image is higher in brightness and lower in saturation -> Lind of image 1
- If the image is lower in brightness and higher in saturation -> kind of image 2

Now, how to determine if the image is higher/lower in brightness/saturation?

Comment: Read about the [HSL and HSV colorspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), and then check [`cv2.cvtColor`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#ga397ae87e1288a81d2363b61574eb8cab) with [`BGR2HSV`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d8/d01/group__imgproc__color__conversions.html#gga4e0972be5de079fed4e3a10e24ef5ef0aa4a7f0ecf2e94150699e48c79139ee12) [color conversion](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_hls) code.

Comment: Sorry... I know how to calculate brightness and saturation of a single rgb color... I meant how I could determine if an entire photo is higher or lower in brightness/saturation...

Answer (score 2):

One simple idea would be to calculate the means of the saturation and value (brightness) channels in the [HSV color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). Then, just set some thresholds for both values to distinguish between the two classes.

Here's Lenna with high brightness and low saturation:

[image: High brightness, low saturation]

Here's Lenna with low brightness and high saturation:

[image: Low brightness, high saturation]

Some code snippet to do the mentioned task using [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/):

```py
import cv2

# Read images
img_hv_ls = cv2.imread('Lenna_high_brightness_low_saturation.png')
img_lv_hs = cv2.imread('Lenna_low_brightness_high_saturation.png')

# Calculate means in HSV color space
mean_hv_ls = cv2.mean(cv2.cvtColor(img_hv_ls, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))
mean_lv_hs = cv2.mean(cv2.cvtColor(img_lv_hs, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV))

# Put information on images
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
cv2.putText(img_hv_ls, 'Mean brightness: ' + '{:.4f}'.format(mean_hv_ls[2]/255), (10, 30), font, 1, (0, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.putText(img_hv_ls, 'Mean saturation: ' + '{:.4f}'.format(mean_hv_ls[1]/255), (10, 60), font, 1, (0, 0, 0), 1)
cv2.putText(img_lv_hs, 'Mean brightness: ' + '{:.4f}'.format(mean_lv_hs[2]/255), (10, 30), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)
cv2.putText(img_lv_hs, 'Mean saturation: ' + '{:.4f}'.format(mean_lv_hs[1]/255), (10, 60), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 1)

cv2.imshow('High brightness, low saturation', img_hv_ls)
cv2.imshow('Low brightness, high saturation', img_lv_hs)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And, that'd be the outputs:

[image: Result: High brightness, low saturation]

[image: Result: Low brightness, high saturation]

Now, check a representative (sub)set of your images, and deduce proper thresholds from the saturation and brightness means for the actual image classification.

Hope that helps!